# Faking a Single Address Space

Tags: performance, multithreading, message-passing, parallel-processing

I have a large scientific computing task that parallelizes very well with SMP, but at too fine grained a level to be easily parallelized via explicit message passing.  I'd like to parallelize it across address spaces and physical machines.  Is it feasible to create a scheduler that would parallelize already multithreaded code across multiple physical computers under the following conditions:

1. The code is already multithreaded and can scale pretty well on SMP configurations.
2. The fact that not all of the threads are running in the same address space or on the same physical machine must be transparent to the program, even if this comes at a significant performance penalty in some use cases.
3. You may assume that all of the physical machines involved are running operating systems and CPU architectures that are binary compatible.
4. Things like locks and atomic operations may be slow (having network latency to deal with and all) but must "just work".

Edits:

5. I only care about throughput, not latency.
6. I'm using the D programming language, and I'm almost sure there's no canned solution.  I'm more interested in whether this is feasible in principle than in a particular canned solution.

Comment: more details please: operating system, environment, programming language etc. How much delay is tolerable?

Comment: The question title reads to me "distributed shared memory", while point 2 says that there is no shared address space, i.e. "distributed memory". Do you need shared memory? If yes, does point 2 require that threads are aware of the environment?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). It provides distributed storage and distributed computing. You can synchronize across processes by using files as locks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like [SCRAMNet](http://nees.berkeley.edu/Facilities/pdf/HybridSim/ComponentsHybridSimulation/scsfcScramnetSystran.pdf), although that requires custom hardware.  I don't know if there is a software-only solution.  Also, it's likely that even if you got it working, you'd find your networked version was actually running slower than when it was previously on a single machine.  You may just have to bite the bullet and re-design your app.

Answer (score 0):

Since your point 2 suggests that you can live with some performance degradation you might want to consider a hybrid approach: SMP within individual machines, message-passing between machines.  I'm not familiar with D so can offer no specific advice.  Further I've seen mixed reviews of the hybrid approach for OpenMP+MPI, but it might suit you and your application.

EDIT: You might want to Google around for 'partitioned global address space' which seems to describe your desired approach quite accurately.  As before, I have no advice on using D for this.